# BigQuery NodeJS SDK not creating native GEOGRAPHY type

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

#### First, simple BigQuery SQL:

We're trying to take the following runnable BigQuery SQL query and convert it to a parameterized query to execute in Node.js:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(
    ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(1 2)') AS lnglat, 
    TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01') AS stamp
  )
])
```

The query simply builds a pseudo-table from an array of STRUCTs. Most notably, the output types match what you'd expect, the stamp column is a BigQuery `TIMESTAMP` type, and `lnglat` is a BigQuery `GEOGRAPHY` type.

#### Now, let's try in Node.js.

Let's substitute the array of BigQuery STRUCTs above, for `@points`, and pass a JavaScript array of Object literals as `params`:

```js
// this is version 5.3.0
const { BigQuery, Geography } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const bigquery = new BigQuery();

(async () => {

  const query = 'SELECT * from UNNEST(@points)';

  const params =  { points: [
    {
      lnglat: new Geography('POINT(1 2)'),
      stamp: BigQuery.timestamp('2020-01-01')
    }
  ] };

  const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob({ query, params });

  // Wait for the query to finish
  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

  // Print the results
  console.log('Rows:');
  console.log(rows);

})();
```

Returns the following result on my CLI:

```sh
> node index.js
Rows:
[
  {
    lnglat: { value: 'POINT(1 2)' },
    stamp: BigQueryTimestamp { value: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' }
  }
]
```

The problem is, despite the NodeJS SDK containing docs around "Geography" [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#.geography), [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#geography), and [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Geography.html), none of these methods seem to actually force BigQuery to construct a native BigQuery `GEOGRAPHY` type inside of BigQuery.

It seems, instead, BigQuery will interpret the `new Geography()` as a `RECORD` type, with a `value` field as indicated in the response above, and also verified by inspecting the temporary (anon) table that is created in the BigQuery UI:

[image: BigQuery UI Schema]

We've tried different variants of geography functions/classes: `Geography`, `BigQuery.Geography`, and `bigquery.Geography`; they all return the same `RECORD` type.

---

Strangely, if we instead query an existing table (as opposed to constructing a pseudo-table at runtime), the result is more consistent with what I would expect:

```sh
Rows:
[ { lnglat: Geography { value: 'POINT(-118.43356046 45.97057312)' } } ]
```

Note the `Geography` type in the response!

---

We are aware that we can fallback to specifying `lnglat` as a JavaScript *string* literal, and the following SQL will convert it into a native GEOGRAPHY by wrapping in a CTE:

```sql
WITH points AS (
  SELECT * from UNNEST(@points)
) 
SELECT * EXCEPT(lnglat), ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(lnglat) AS lnglat FROM points
```

But unfortunately, we want to use this pseudotable as a filter against a much larger on-disk table, and using this CTE-wrapper eliminates the ability for that query (not illustrated here) to leverage clustering.  Clustering is *very* important for cost savings and execution performance. I can elaborate more on this if you request.

At the end of the day, it still doesn't explain why native GEOGRAPHYs are not materializing in the pseudo-table.

### Question:

How do we use BigQuery NodeJS SDK to construct a native BigQuery `GEOGRAPHY` type, similar to what we can do with `BigQuery.timestamp()` (above), without CTEs?

Comment: This is a bug in the library. I've opened a fix: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/pull/877

Comment: it's great to see that get fixed! thank you @SteffanyBrown